# how to filter out/exclude some indexes from a CGPoint array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of CGPoints (`spritePositions`) and I would like to create SKSpriteNode's with a selected number of positions (leaving specific indexes of the out). Please see code below:

```
CreateSprite(missingIndexes: [int])    {

    //for (index, value) in enumerate(spritePositions)  filtering out/excluding missingIndexes array {
         var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spriteImage")
         sprite.position = value
         addChild(sprite)
     }
}
```

Comment: there is a higher order function called filter that works on arrays to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the contains function on the missingIndexes array to filter out your indices. If the index is not contained in your missingIndexes process as normal. If the index is containted in missingIndexes, do nothing.

**Swift 1.2:**

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(spritePositions) {
    if !contains(missingIndexes, index) {
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spriteImage")
        sprite.position = value
        addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
for (index, value) in spritePositions.enumerate() {
    if !missingIndexes.contains(index) {
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spriteImage")
        sprite.position = value
        addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 1.2:**

```
var filteredObjects = spritePositions.filter { !contains(missingIndexes, find(spritePositions, $0)!)}
```

gets a list by filtering the indices

```
for object in filteredObjects {
    print(object)
}
```

uses that in a loop

Not necessarily the best way to do it, just a way using filter, which will allow you to keep the filtered array if you need it later.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option would be to use a combination of the `Set` type and the `map` function. The below snippet is for Swift 1.2.

```
let missingIndexes: [Int] = ...
let spritePositions: [CGPoint] = ...

map(Set(0 ..< count(spritePositions)).subtract(missingIndexes), { index -> Void in
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spriteImage")
    sprite.position = spritePositions[index]
    addChild(sprite)
})
```

This is more efficient than repeatedly calling `contains` on the `missingIndexes` array.